# Removing a set number of random character from multiple files

Tags: command-line, bash

I have multiple file like those:

```
test01 - checking - Heart-ta-mPFnno34-192K-1651117354964.txt
test01 - checking - Hard-ta-mPFnno34-192K-1651117354965.txt
test01 - checking - Strong Blur-ta-mPFnno34-192K-1651117354966.txt
test01 - checking - Better Topic-ta-mPFnno34-192K-1651117354967.txt
```

The 30 characters after **Heart**, **Hard**, etc... is random except for the first '-' and there is always 30 characters including the first '-'.

I already removed some unwanted character from the files using the `mmv` command like this

```
mmv 'test01 - *' '#1'
```

but I don't know how to remove a set of random character.
I tried using the `cut` command.

```
echo "Hello world" | rev | cut -c 3- | rev
```

It output `Hello wo`
But I don't know how to do it with multiple file

Is there a way to remove those character with the `cut` command and can you tell me how?
And if there is an easier method, I will gladly take it.

Comment: Couldn't you have done it all with mmv - something like `mmv -n 'test01 - * - *-*.txt' '#1 - #2.txt'` for example? What is the desired final outcome?

Comment: Awesome, didn't know I could use it like that.
The desired result was just like this one ```checking - Heart.txt```
Thanks for your reply it help me a lot

Comment: Okay I ran a test and discover some file change the base name. I used music title but still got those 30 number at the end.
```MusicSample - Davuiside - Feeling-cNuZ5Di3L0g-192k-1651116994205.mp3```

I can't figure it out how to remove those with the ```mmv```.
Any idea on how I can remove those?

Comment: What is the output you expect from this? Do all file names start with the specific string `test01 - checking - `?

Comment: I expect an output like this : ```test01 - checking - Heart-ta-mPFnno34-192K-1651117354964.txt -> Checking - Heart```.
Not all start with ```test01 - checking``` some start with ```MusicSample - Artist - Title-cNuZ5Di3L0g-192k-1651116994205.mp3``` or ```VideoSample - Title-cNuZ5Di3L0g-192k-1651116994205.mp3```. And for those one, i expect an output Artist - Title. 
Every file end with a 30 character long code like this one ```-ta-mPFnno34-192K-1651117354966``` with an extension ```.mp3```